# Why UITabBar is hiding its title name

Tags: iphone, uitabbar

I added UITabBar and I had set its title name from the nib file but it is being disappear. I got the thing is that it is there but tabbar size is small so it is not showing there. I have attached simulator image and here is my flow of program.

1) Loading viewcontroller, it is appearing for 3 sec
2) after 3 sec another viewcontroller is being loaded and it contains UITabBar controller.

[image: UITabBar output]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the title name and icon in the tabbarController by clicking on each tab bar item.